# Show Hide <li> Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I am creating a simple html search box with live list filtering. The user will enter text in search box and the list will filter according to the user entered data. The problem I am facing is that my list is not showing up after I used the code to hide the "li" elements. As for the hiding list part the css is working its function very accurately but the query function is not listing up the results. Here is the Code...

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  $(".menu-hide").show(); // <-- code to show the list
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.menu-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<ul id="myUL" class="menu-hide">
  <li><a href="#">John</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Angela</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

sorry for the long code because as a student I am new to asking question prciesly.

Comment: They will show up when entering text, do you want show list all the time

Comment: @Bhuwan was there something wrong with my edit :-)

Comment: they are not showing up while entering text. and I want them to just display the result typed in the search box. not all the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lots more code there than needed, and only a single line of jQuery, which is easily eliminated.

Also, your demo doesn't actually load the jQuery library, so that would be an issue

Here's a rewrite that maintains something close to your initial approach, but simplifies the DOM selection using `querySelectorAll`, and drops the unnecessary library.

Click for demo...

```js
function myFunction() {
  var filter = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toUpperCase().trim();

  document.querySelector(".menu-hide").style.display = filter ? "block" : "none";

  var a = document.querySelectorAll("#myUL li a");

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.menu-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL" class="menu-hide">
  <li><a href="#">John</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Angela</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

Here's one that reworks it to further shorten and simplify it. It uses a `for-of` loop to iterate the collection, and the conditional operator to set the `.display`.

Click for demo...

```js
function myFunction() {
  var filter = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toUpperCase().trim();
  
  document.querySelector(".menu-hide").style.display = filter ? "block" : "none";

  for (const a of document.querySelectorAll("#myUL li a")) {
    a.style.display =
      a.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter) ? "block" : "";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: none;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL" class="menu-hide">
  <li><a href="#">John</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Angela</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: bundle of thanks for fixing up my code. In your edited code the list shows up while entering the values in the search box but after searching a value the list doesn't go back hidden. The whole list shows up after the search. can it be hidden after the search field is empty again.??

sorry for silly question. I am a newbie :)

Comment: @DamagedBroadcast: Yes, I wasn't sure what you wanted there. I'll updated both demos to hide the list when the input is empty.

Comment: Thanks a million :) you helped me learn a lot from this little snippet. I was confused and was wandering in the sea of search pages with no luck. Bundle of thanks again for helping me out..